# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I've been getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

`DISHES` object is imported from **dishes.js** and loaded into the state object dishes in the **App.js** Component, then it's passed as props to **MenuComponent.js** through Menu component when rendered in **App.js**

I don't know why, everything seems correct, this is an assignment which is part of an online course and I've seen corrections made by other people who did the course and they seem to be doing the exact same thing as me and it works for them.

**Output**:

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Navbar, NavbarBrand} from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css';
import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import { DISHES } from "./shared/dishes";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**MenuComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedDish: null
    };
  }

  onDishSelect(dish) {
    this.setState({selectedDish: dish});
  }

  renderDish(dish) {
    if (dish != null) {
      return (
        <Card>
          <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
      return (
        <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {menu}
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

**dishes.js**

```
export const DISHES =
[
    {
    id: 0,
    name:'Uthappizza',
    image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    label:'Hot',
    price:'4.99',
    description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]                        },
    {
    id: 1,
    name:'Zucchipakoda',
    image: 'assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    label:'',
    price:'1.99',
    description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name:'Vadonut',
    image: 'assets/images/vadonut.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    label:'New',
    price:'1.99',
    description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    id: 3,
    name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
    image: 'assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
    category: 'dessert',
    label:'',
    price:'2.99',
    description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]
    }
];
```

Comment: By making sure `this.props.dishes` is not undefined i.e. it does have a value that is an array

Comment: You should bind your function

Comment: @DennisVash I binded all the functions in MenuComponent.js still nothing

Comment: @Manish turns out DISHES object isn't getting loaded into the dishes state in App.js,
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try logging `DISHES` and `this.state.dishes` for starters

Comment: I logged them, they happen to be loaded with the data from dishes.js

Comment: In your Menu constructor, if you do console.log(this.props) after super(), what do you get?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I get this.props is successfully loaded with the contents of state.dishes

Comment: Can you try `this.props && this.props.dishes.map()`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava It worked, thanks, can you tell me what is the && in this context, I'm quite new to reactjs, Also it'd be cool if you'd post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this component `<Menu dishes={this.state.dishes}/>` which expects a `dishes` prop.

Now in `<App>`, you call `this.setState()` but it is asynchronous, and on the first render of `<App>` (and therefore of `<Menu>`), the value `this.state.dishes` is still `undefined`, hence `this.props` in `<Menu>` is also `undefined`

When it does update, there is a re-render, and the `<App>` and `<Menu>` are rendered with the correct values.

So you can add a check for `undefined` so that the `.map()` runs only when `this.props` have a value.

That is what `this.props && this.props.dishes.map()` does. Essentially it means `if(this.props){ this.props.dishes.map() }`, so when `this.props` is `undefined`, the second expression is not executed.

After `setState` is complete, `this.props` is defined, and you get your result.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any props undefined value, you can use the library [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types), where you define your props default values, so that if the props value is not transferred to your component, your component will still have a default value to behave as expected. It's useful in the case where your props are not defined from the very start for example (which is probably the case here).

To do so, install the library:

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

Then in your `MenuComponent` file, add the import at the top of your file:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

and finally, at the end of your file, add this props type check and default value:

```js
// Define the props types to check
Menu.propTypes = {
  dishes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    image: PropTypes.string,
    category: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    price: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string,
    comment: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
      rating: PropTypes.number,
      comment: PropTypes.string,
      author: PropTypes.string,
      date: PropTypes.string,
    })),
  })),
};

// Define here the default value to attribute to your dishes props
Menu.defaultProps = {
  dishes: [],
};

export default Menu;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for the great effort but sadly It didn't work :/

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by it didn't work ? What did you try, what errors did you get ?

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the same class and I copied and pasted your code with no issues. Make sure your index.js file looks like this as well. If that is not the issue then maybe your imports were correctly installed. Since there is an issue with the MenuComponent maybe react was not downloaded properly.

Not sure what the issue is, but I don't believe it is something with the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```